# Plotly y-axis acting funny

Tags: python, plotly

So, my bar chart y-axis has been acting funny. Here is the chart,

[X is a list of Universities, while Y-axis is a value between 0 and 100.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi7hf.png)

Instead of a range, say 0 - 100, the values are all over the place. I dont understand why. Here is my code:

```
uni_list = ['Harvard University',
            'California Institute of Technology',
            'Massachusetts Institute of Technology',
            'Stanford University',
            'Princeton University',
            'University of Cambridge',
            'University of Oxford',
            'University of California, Berkeley',
            'Imperial College London',
            'Yale University']
year_list = [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
int_std = pd.DataFrame(columns=['university_name', 'year', 'income'])
count = 0
print(int_std)
for university in uni_list:
    for year in year_list:
        int_std.loc[count, 'university_name'] = university
        int_std.loc[count, 'year'] = year
        int_std.loc[count, 'income'] = times[(times['university_name'] == university) & (times['year'] == year)]['income'].iloc[0]
        count = count + 1

bar1 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2011].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'yellow', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2011')
bar2 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2012].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'orange', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2012')
bar3 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2013].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'green', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2013')
bar4 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2014].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'blue', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2014')
bar5 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2015].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'red', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2015')
bar6 = go.Bar(x = uni_list,
              y = int_std[int_std['year'] == 2016].income.values,
              marker = dict(color = 'grey', line=dict(color='white', width = 1)),
              name = '2016')
fig3 = go.Figure(data = [bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5], layout = go.Layout(barmode = 'group'))
py.plot(fig3)
```

The dataset I've used is from here:

https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/plotly-tutorial-for-beginners

I've noticed I get this issue for any bar chart I try to plot. And I can't figure out why. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of graph you are expecting. x=?, y=? and legends=?

Comment: I am expecting a grouped bar graph like in the image. The y-axis has to be from 1 - 100 in ascending order like typically in a graph. But as you can see in the image, its not. I need that fixed

Comment: In go.figure you are putting bar1, bar2, bar3... so, probably it's merging different y axis in one plot the simplest method to do that you need to select x= university, y=income and  color=year. you can put labels in same conditions. see the documentation,

Comment: don't try to right complex code for simple solution see the documentation,
https://plotly.com/python/legend/